# C array being overwritten/deleted? very confused

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, nodes, overwrite

I am working on a project in C and it is working great except for one function which seems to be overwriting my array and writing weird numbers such as 1970802352 which keeps count of word occurrences in a file

this is my header file:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
struct Node_{
        char* word;
        //array holding names of files word occurs in 
        char **filesIn;
        int numFilesIn;
        //array holding count of how many times word occured in file
        int* occursIn;
        struct Node_ *next;
        int isHead;
};

typedef struct Node_ Node;

int insert(char *wordToAdd, char *File);

int addOccur(Node *addedTo, char *File);

Node *createNode(char *wordToAdd, char *File);

void destroyNodes();

#endif
```

and this is the function that keeps overwriting the array:

```
Node *head;
int insert(char *wordToAdd, char *File){
        if(head == NULL){
                Node *new;
                new = createNode(wordToAdd, File);
                new->isHead = 1;
                head = new;
                return 0;
        }
        else{
                Node *trace;
                trace = head;
                char *traceWord;
                int wordSize;
                wordSize = strlen(trace->word);
                traceWord = (char*) malloc(wordSize + 1);
                strcpy(traceWord, trace->word);
                int a =strcmp(wordToAdd, traceWord);
                free(traceWord);
                if(a == 0){
                        int b = addOccur(trace, File);
                        //printf("addOccur returned %d\n", b);
                        return 0;
                }
                if(a < 0){
                        Node *Insert = createNode(wordToAdd, File);
                        trace->isHead = 0;
                        Insert->isHead = 1;
                        Insert->next = trace;
                        head = Insert;
                        return 0;
                }
                else{


                        Node *backTrace;
                        backTrace = head;

                        while(trace->next != NULL){
                                trace = trace->next;
                                traceWord = trace->word;
                                a = strcmp(wordToAdd, traceWord);
                                if(a < 0){
                                        Node* Insert = createNode(wordToAdd, File);
                                        Insert->next = trace;
                                        backTrace->next = Insert;
                                        return 0;
                                }
                                if(a == 0){
                                        addOccur(trace, File);
                                        //free(wordToAdd);
                                        return 0;
                                }
                                if(a > 0){
                                        backTrace = trace;
                                        continue;
                                }
                        }
                        Node *Insert = createNode(wordToAdd, File);
                        trace->next = Insert;
                        return 0;
                }
        }
        return 1;
}
```

and the other functions are:

```
Node* createNode(char *wordToAdd, char *File){
        Node *new;
        new =   (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        memset(new, 0, sizeof(Node));
        new->word = wordToAdd;
        char **newArray;
        newArray = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        newArray[0] = File;
        new->filesIn = newArray;
        int a[1];
        a[0] = 1;
        new->occursIn = a;
        //new->occursIn[0] = 1;
        new->numFilesIn = 1;
        return new;
}

int addOccur(Node *addedTo, char *File){

        char **fileList = addedTo->filesIn;
        char *fileCheck;
        int i = 0;
        int fileNums = addedTo->numFilesIn;
        for(i = 0; i < fileNums; i++){
                fileCheck = fileList[i];
                if(strcmp(fileCheck, File) == 0){
                        int *add1;
                        add1 = addedTo->occursIn;
                        int j = add1[i];
                        j++;
                        add1[i] = j;
                        return 0;
                }
        }

        int numberOfFilesIn;
        numberOfFilesIn = addedTo->numFilesIn;
        char **newList = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * numberOfFilesIn + sizeof(char*));
        i = 0;
        char *dest;
        char *src;
for(i = 0; i < numberOfFilesIn; i++){
                src = fileList[i];
                int len;
                len = strlen(src);
                dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
                strcpy(dest, src);
                newList[i] = dest;
                }
        int len2;
        len2 = strlen(File);
        newList[i] = File;
        free(fileList);
        int r = addedTo->numFilesIn;
        r++;
        addedTo->numFilesIn = r;
        addedTo->filesIn = newList;
        i = 0;
        int *g;
        g =  addedTo->occursIn;
        int count2;
        count2 = addedTo->numFilesIn;
        count2++;
        int a[count2];
        for(i = 0; i < count2 -1; i++){
                a[i] = g[i];
        }
        a[count2 - 1] = 1;
        return 0;
}
```

When going to gdb i notice that the value of

> head->occursIn[0]

changes after the line

> wordSize = strlen(trace->word);

and I have no clue why.

Comment: Does this happen with optimizations on? If so then debugger can be unreliable to pin point the exact line of error. If executing this line really changes something quite unrelated then it's hella weird. I mean even if you confused pointers somewhere, I don't think that `strcmp` touches anything. So `a` would need to lie in the same place as `head->occursIn[0]`. Only other options, I know, for such weirdness is UB and/or stack corruption.

Comment: @luk32 yes it happens with optimizations on and off, wrote the wrong line for where it happened and corrected it. I noticed my code seems to work fine for every node except the head.

Comment: Please show your code for functions createNode() and addOccur().

Comment: @RichardSchwartz ok I put it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CreateNode() function, you are not allocating storage for the occursIn array. You are simply declaring a local array within the function and then assigning the occursIn pointer:

```
int a[1];
a[0] = 1;
new->occursIn = a;
```

The array a[1] goes away when the createNode function returns, so at that point your occursIn pointer is pointing to a value that is subject to being overwritten.

And even if the storage was allocated correctly in createNode, you've set a fixed size for the array but your whole strategy depends on that array having an element for each file; and in addOccurs you don't do anything to allocate a new larger array for a new file.

You may want to re-evaluate your strategy and switch to using lists instead of arrays.

Comment: Ok yeah thinking about it now a list is probably a lot easier to implement. Thanks!